# How to populate JavaScript variables with PHP variables?

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I must use PHP variables (from DB) to populate JavaScript variables like the one below:

```
var oMain = new CMain({
  mon:  100,        
  min_: 10,      
  max_: 25,     
  time_bet: 0,       
  time_winner: 500,  
  win_occurrence: 65, 
  cash:100000,  
  fullscreen:true, 
  check_orientation:true,  
  show_credits:true,  
  num_before_ads:1 
});
```

I tried to `echo` my PHP variables directly in JavaScript (e.g. `mon: <?php echo $mon; ?>,`) but this does not work.

What do you recommend?

Comment: did you try var `mon = " <?php echo $mon; ?>";`

Comment: `mon: '<?php echo $mon; ?>',`

Comment: `mon: parseInt('<?php echo $mon; ?>',10)`

Comment: Is you javascript in the php-document or in a separate js-file? You should also give a more detailed description of what _"but this does not work."_ means. PHP error? JS-error in the console? Computer caught on fire?

Comment: No new info? Well, then we're kind of stuck here...

Comment: @RedBottle thanks the double quote is the one working. Strangely , signe quotes fails ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should surround the php code with quotations, because this php statement `<?php echo $mon; ?>` will return string, and it to be readable by js, it should be surrounded with quotations.

`mon: '<?php echo $mon; ?>';`

EDIT: if you are printing number, you should parse it, for example:

`mon: parseInt('<?php echo $mon; ?>',10);`

`mon: parseFloat('<?php echo $mon; ?>');`

Comment: Quotes are not needed by javascript if the value is not a string.

Comment: Why should you parse numbers like that? if `$mon` contains a valid integer or float, you can print it directly, without any quotes or parsing. And currently, we don't even know if the OP is trying to echo the variable in a PHP-file or not...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson its safer to parse it, sometimes you can't guarantee that the php var has a valid integer or float.

Comment: Then I would recommend doing it in PHP instead: `echo (int) $mon` or `echo (float) $mon`

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to do a small API where you call by ajax and retrieve your values by JSON.

```
<?php
 $result =  array(
                  'mon' =>  $mon,        
                  'min_'=> $min,      
                  'max_'=> $max,     
                  'time_bet'=> $time_bet,       
                  'time_winner'=> $time_winner,  
                  'win_occurrence'=> $win_ocurr, 
                  'cash'=>$cash,  
                  'fullscreen'=>$fullscreen, 
                  'check_orientation'=>$orientation,  
                  'show_credits'=>$credits,  
                  'num_before_ads'=>$num_before_ads 
           );
echo json_encode($result);

?>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
       if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           //manipulate your result
       }
       else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
          alert('There was an error 400');
       }
       else {
           alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
       }
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_file.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

If php already loaded and has frontend, put into hidden inputs or data-attributes. Mess PHP echoes inside JS is ugly and a bad practice too.

Comment: Best practices says that you should use GET when your GETting data.